# Does lock Lock the whole object?

Tags: java, multithreading, concurrency, operating-system

```
class Resource{
  public Lock lock = new ReentrantLock();

  public void A(){
    lock.lock();
    try{ .. }
    finally{
      lock.unlock();
    }
  }

  public void B(){
    lock.lock();
    try{ .. }
    finally{
      lock.unlock();
    }

  }


  public void C(){
    ... //Nothing to do with lock here
  }
}
```

Now lets say I have 3 threads `T1, T2, T3` and one `Resource` instance called `resource`.

The first thing that runs is `T1 calls resource.A()`. Now, lets say `resource.A()` takes 1500 minutes, if `T2` calls `resource.B()` during the 100th minute (meaning the call from `T1` is running), what happens?

When I perforamed the `lock.lock()` did it lock the *object* or did it lock the *method*?

Thanks

Comment: Lock locks the lock.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Lock is obtained by a **thread**. So if one thread X holds the lock, other threads can't obtain the lock until it released by X.

In your case, method B can't obtain the lock before method A release the lock.

Comment: Ok I see, so if `T2` calls `resource.B()`, it will wait until `T1` gives up the `lock`?

Comment: you are right. If host of lock don't give up the lock, the lock will be never available to others.

Comment: Ok and one more question. Is it possible for `T2` to call `resource.C()`, the method `C()` does nothing with the lock so if `resource.A()` is running that is called by `T1` and locked by `T1`, can `T2` call `resource.C()` midway without problems?

Comment: Yes, it could be run `resource.C()` at any time since it does nothing with the lock.

Answer (score 0):

> The first thing that runs is T1 calls `resource.a()`. Now, lets say `resource.a()` takes 1500 minutes, if T2 calls `resource.b()` during the 100th minute (meaning the call from T1 is running), what happens?

What happens is that T2 is blocked until T1's call to `resource.b()` releases the lock.  In this case, it  will be blocked for 1400 minutes.

> When I performed the `lock.lock()` did it lock the object or did it lock the method?

Neither really.

You didn't lock the `Resource` instance:

1. The `Resource` instance has an *intrinsic* lock ... which is not being used here.
2. Other threads calling `resource.c()` won't be blocked.

You didn't actually lock the methods.  The locking is *inside* the methods.  So for example, method `a` or method `b` could do stuff *before* calling `lock.lock()`, or after releasing it.

What you actually did is that you acquired the lock on the `ReentrantLock` object.
In this case, two out of three of the methods *use* that lock object, so you are *in effect* locking the *relevant parts* of those methods against calls by different threads.

However, if the calls were made by the same thread (e.g. if `a()` called `b()`) then the 2nd call would not be blocked.  (That is what "reentrant" means in this context.)

Comment: Thanks for such a great answer. "However, if the calls were made by the same thread (e.g. if a() called b()) then the 2nd call would not be blocked. (That is what "reentrant" means in this context.)" -- I am a little confused here. So saying `T1` called `resource.A()` and `T1` acquired the lock, if `resource.A()` calls `resource.B()` it wont be an issue even though there is a `lock.lock()` in `resource.B()` as well? How does that work? Thanks

Comment: 1) Please respect Java naming conventions.  The methods should be called `a`, `b`, and `c`. Not `A`, `B` and `C`.

Comment: 2) Like I said, this is what reentrant means.  If a thread holds a lock and then calls `lock()` on the same lock object, the implementation says "go ahead ... you are already holding that lock".  Under the hood, it just increments a counter.  And decrements it in the corresponding `lock.unlock()`

Comment: Just one more question actually. What does object's intrinsic lock mean? I read the docs from Oracle but I am finding it very confusing as a beginner. Is it possible for you to provide a simple explanation?



I mean, doesnt `T1` now own the intrinsic lock of `resource`?

Comment: Nope.  The intrinisc lock is the one you lock with `synchronized(this) { ... }` on (for example) a `Resource`.

Answer (score 0):

> did it lock the object or did it lock the method?

Neither.  It locked the object's *[intrinsic monitor](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/concurrency/locksync.html)*.

A common rookie mistake is to think that if thread A synchronizes on some object, o, then other threads will not be able to use or modify object o.  That is not true at all.  The only thing that thread A prevents by entering a `synchronized(o)` block is, it prevents other threads from synchronizing on the same object at the same time.

If you want to ensure that only one thread at a time can use or modify an object, then you must ensure that *every* place where your code uses or modifies it is wrapped in a `synchronized` block that synchronizes on the same object.

---

Some programmers prefer to use a separate, private lock object:

```
private static final Object lock = new Object();

public void mymethod(...) {
    synchronized(lock) {
        ...access to this is protected by lock...
    }
}
```

The advantage is, it denies other classes the ability to mess with the lock that protects your class's private data.